# Gitolite - adding new public key - could not symlink

Tags: git, ubuntu, symlink, gitolite

I've installed the latest version of gitolite on Ubuntu:

I'm running

```
gitolite setup -pk user2.pub
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
FATAL: could not symlink /home/git/.gitolite/hooks/common/update to MyRepository.
git/hooks
  at /home/git/gitolite/src/lib/Gitolite/Conf/Store.pm line 330
```

Any thoughts on what is going on?

---

EDIT:
Ok - so the directory

```
MyRepository.git/hooks
```

doesn't exist. There is only

```
MyRepository.git/.git/hooks/
```

What is going on with gitolite?

Comment: do you have write permission?

Comment: I've tested giving the source and target of the symlink 777 permissions - still the same error.

Comment: well.. it usually helps to install it all over again ^_^ but I know this is not a kind of advice you are looking for..

Comment: Does `MyRepository.git/hooks` *already* contain a file name '`update`'?

Comment: Thanks VonC - it was a user error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`store_common()`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/b2a3509e63a834f8bff3f45de74fcd58baf2c6a5/src/lib/Gitolite/Conf/Store.pm#L326) includes:

```
# override/propagate gitolite defined hooks for all repos
ln_sf( "$rc{GL_ADMIN_BASE}/hooks/common", "*", "$repo.git/hooks" );
```

That, in turn, calls [`ln_sf()`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/b2a3509e63a834f8bff3f45de74fcd58baf2c6a5/src/lib/Gitolite/Common.pm#L162)

```
sub ln_sf {
    trace( 3, @_ );
    my ( $srcdir, $glob, $dstdir ) = @_;
    for my $hook ( glob("$srcdir/$glob") ) {
        $hook =~ s/$srcdir\///;
        unlink "$dstdir/$hook";
        symlink "$srcdir/$hook", "$dstdir/$hook" or croak "could not symlink $srcdir/$hook to $dstdir\n";
    }
}
```

`dstdir` here seems incomplete. It should be `/home/git/repositories/MyRepository.git/hooks`.

That can be because of anc incorrect initial setup.

Comment: for me it was an incomplete setup (had a normal git repo in my repositories folder for some reason)

Comment: sub ln_sf contains this line "symlink "$srcdir/$hook", "$dstdir/$hook" or croak "could not symlink $srcdir/$hook to $dstdir\n";". Here what is symlink? Is it a linux command or another perl function?

Comment: @sdram a perl function (http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/symlink.html, http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html)

Answer (score 0):

I saw the mentioned error when trying to import an old repository into gitolite.

The gitolite repositories directory contains the ".git" folder of "bare" repositories. That means if one want to import a repository into gitolite, he should do the following:
-- be sure the oldrepo is a bare git repository
-- run the folloeing as a gtolite user

```
cd $HOME
cp -R oldrepo/.git repositories/oldrepo.git
gitolite setup
```

My mistake was to put the old repository as a directory that contains a ".git". I've find out it was wrong.

For example my old repository:

```
os-HP /home/gitrepo/repositories $ ll scripts/.git/
total 52
drwxrwsrwx   8 gitrepo gitrepo 4096 Jan 25 10:59 .
drwxrwsrwx   3 gitrepo gitrepo 4096 Jul 26 15:48 ..
drwxrwsrwx   2 gitrepo gitrepo 4096 Jan 25 10:49 branches
-rwxrwxrwx   1 gitrepo gitrepo    8 Jan 25 10:53 COMMIT_EDITMSG
-rw-rw-r--   1 gitrepo gitrepo   91 Jan 25 10:59 config
-rwxrwxrwx   1 gitrepo gitrepo   73 Jan 25 10:49 description
-rwxrwxrwx   1 gitrepo gitrepo   23 Jan 25 10:49 HEAD
drwxrwsrwx   2 gitrepo gitrepo 4096 Jan 25 10:49 hooks
-rwxrwxrwx   1 gitrepo gitrepo  264 Jan 25 10:53 index
drwxrwsrwx   2 gitrepo gitrepo 4096 Jan 25 10:49 info
drwxrwsrwx   3 gitrepo gitrepo 4096 Jan 25 10:52 logs
drwxrwsrwx 133 gitrepo gitrepo 4096 Jun 28 08:50 objects
drwxrwsrwx   4 gitrepo gitrepo 4096 Jan 25 10:49 refs
```

Comparing to the testing repository that is shipped with gitolite:

```
ey ~/repositories $ ll testing.git/
total 40
drwx------  7 gitrepo gitrepo 4096 Jul 26 02:37 .
drwx------  5 gitrepo gitrepo 4096 Jul 26 08:46 ..
drwx------  2 gitrepo gitrepo 4096 Jul 26 02:37 branches
-rw-------  1 gitrepo gitrepo   66 Jul 26 02:37 config
-rw-------  1 gitrepo gitrepo    0 Jul 26 05:16 git-daemon-export-ok
-rw-------  1 gitrepo gitrepo  120 Jul 26 05:16 gl-conf
-rw-------  1 gitrepo gitrepo   23 Jul 26 02:37 HEAD
drwx------  2 gitrepo gitrepo 4096 Jul 26 05:13 hooks
drwx------  2 gitrepo gitrepo 4096 Jul 26 02:37 info
drwx------ 10 gitrepo gitrepo 4096 Jul 26 03:05 objects
drwx------  4 gitrepo gitrepo 4096 Jul 26 02:37 refs
```